# Is there a difference between System.Windows.Clipboard and System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard?

Tags: wpf, clipboard

Is there a difference between System.Windows.Clipboard and System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard?

The documentation for the System.Windows.Forms version specifically states that to store an object on the clipboard it has to be serializable and your app has to have the STA model, but the documentation for the System.Windows version doesn't list either as a requirement.  Is it?  Why have two classes?  What's the difference?

In case it matters, our app is WPF and yes I know the former is for WPF and the latter for Windows.Forms... but why?  Why not just always use the System.Windows version even with forms-based apps considering it's just a reference and is less restrictive in its use, and an object is just an object in .NET.

Comment: We have WinForms code which has used System.Windows.Clipboard since the dawn of time which is just now breaking.  Switching to System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard resolved the issue.  WHY?

Comment: That's my question! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple: `System.Windows.Clipboard` (in PresentationCore.dll) is intended for use with WPF, while `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard` (in System.Windows.Forms.dll) is meant for Windows Forms.

You'll often come across seemingly identical classes in both assemblies; this is because WPF and WinForms are based on sufficiently different systems that many framework APIs have to be implemented differently. I haven't really worked with the system clipboard myself, but my guess is that it has something to do with WinForms' relative proximity to the low-level Win32 APIs. I wouldn't be certain, though.

Since you're working with WPF, you should use `System.Windows.Clipboard`, since ostensibly the implementation is different for WPF than for WinForms.

Comment: While yes I know you're supposed to use them in their respective platforms, but that doesn't explain the difference, and why one side has a restriction whereas the other doesn't, yet they are talking to the same COM-based clipboard.  That's what I'm wondering.  For instance, since the System.Windows version seems to be much less restrictive, why wouldn't even Windows Forms app use that one?

Comment: I don't think there's going to be any more of an answer than this so I'll accept yours.  Still, regarding the serialization issue, I don't know if it's an error in the docs, or you're actually allowed to use a non-serializable version of the data in the WPF version.

Answer (score 0):

System.Windows namespace is about WPF(new way of creating GUI in Windows), while System.Windows.Forms namespace contains elements about Forms(old style).

Comment: See my comment to @BoltClock above, but in short, that's not explaining the difference.  That's explaining the usage.

Comment: I think the difference is that WPF directly works with DirectX for UI, while Forms uses GDI+. So WPF may be using multiple threads for working with GPU and other components.

Comment: But the clipboard has nothing to do with the UI.  It's data behind the scenes, so nothing about that should matter.

Comment: Did you try using WPF clipboard in a Forms application? Since Thread Safe > Non-Thread Safe, maybe it works.